# Bootstrap3 Typeahead - Calling a function in 'Remote'

Tags: c#, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js, twitter-bootstrap-3

I upgraded to Bootstrap version 3.0 and I do see that the typeahead module does not exist. I am using web services and I had used the following method to call my function and populate my dataset. However, with the twitter typeahead.js, how do I call my function or how do I still use the old typeahead module? Your help is much appreciated. Thanks.

```
            $("#searchVendor").typeahead({
            source: function (query) {
                    vieModel.callWebServiceFunctionList(counter1, query, isListCleared);   
       });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typeahead.js doesn't have a way of directly using a function as the `source`. The standard way to pass a query value is with a URL string containing `%QUERY` in the `remote` property:

```
$("#searchVendor").typeahead({
            remote: '.../data.json?name=%QUERY'   
});
```

However, this probably isn't enough in your case. `remote` can also be an object, with a `url` and a `replace` function that is applied to the URL.

So, make a function like `callWebServiceFunctionList` that just returns the URL instead of actually calling the web service.

```
$("#searchVendor").typeahead({
            remote: {
               url: '.../data.json?counter=%COUNTER&query=%QUERY&isListCleared=%ISLISTCLEARED',
               replace: function(url, query) {
                  return url.replace('%COUNTER', counter1).replace('%QUERY', query).replace('%ISLISTCLEARED', isListCleared);
               }
});
```

[See the docs](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/#remote) for the `remote` object.

Alternatively, you could get the JS for just the typeahead portion of Bootstrap 2.x, and while you might run into problems with the formatting, [it seems to work fine by itself](http://jsfiddle.net/BDAWd/) (JSFiddle demo).